# how to access SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems() by ctypes

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, pywin32, cx-freeze

I want to build a cross-platform application ,I used a windows API called [SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Although I found example called it by pywin32,but pywin32 is not available on Linux , I  don't want to  call a Windows API on linux,just don't want to make another code version for Linux,so I wonder how to access it by ctypes? yes,this API cannot be called on Linux ,I just want to make it silent in the code so that I can freeze the Python scripts into executables by cx_Freeze without pywin32 module-missing error happend .

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
import os
def launch_file_explorer(path, files):
     '''
     Given a absolute base path and names of its children (no path), open
     up one File Explorer window with all the child files selected
     '''
     folder_pidl = shell.SHILCreateFromPath(path,0)[0]
     desktop = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder()
     shell_folder = desktop.BindToObject(folder_pidl, None,shell.IID_IShellFolder)
     name_to_item_mapping = dict([(desktop.GetDisplayNameOf(item, shellcon.SHGDN_FORPARSING|shellcon.SHGDN_INFOLDER), item) for item in shell_folder])
     print(name_to_item_mapping)
     to_show = []
     for file in files:
         if file in name_to_item_mapping:
             to_show.append(name_to_item_mapping[file])
         # else:
             # raise Exception('File: "%s" not found in "%s"' % (file, path))


     shell.SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(folder_pidl, to_show, 0)






p=r'E:\aa'
print(os.listdir(p))
launch_file_explorer(p, os.listdir(p))
```

Comment: You can implement the [IShellFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775075) interface with [comtypes](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes), a COM framework that uses ctypes. Here's an [example](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=9636188) using the `IUnknown` interface. Search for "interface IShellFolder : IUnknown" in shobjidl.idl in the Windows SDK. The methods are defined in VTable order, starting at index 3.

Comment: The [_WinHttpRequest](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure/http/winhttp.py) class in the Windows Azure SDK is an example of using just ctypes to access COM methods. They define only a subset of the interface, by vtable index.

Comment: ctypes won't let you use Windows API calls on Linux, because those functions just aren't there. You'll have to work out how to do something equivalent on Linux.

Comment: @eryksun: I'm a bit confused about what the OP is trying to do. The 'missing modules' warning from cx_Freeze is a warning, not an error - it shouldn't prevent you building an executable.